# Is there a symbolic math package for octave?

Tags: symbolic-computation, octave, sagemath

I am using Octave (3.6) on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS. I want to do some research involving symbolic math. I was thinking of downloading [sage](http://www.sagemath.org) (I just found about it today) - but thought I'd better ask in here - at least, I'm already familiar with Octave.

Comment: maxima is pretty good at symbolic math it is available in ubuntu. maple is also a very good option, but it is not free. octave is similar to matlab, and you can do symbolic math in matlab, but it's more complicated, because you have to define the symbolic variables and use them in a certan way.

Comment: maxima is what Sage uses to do symbolic math

Comment: Sage uses *many* symbolic computation packages: Maxima, Singular, etc. For each functionality, it picks the most suitable algorithm from all the packages. It also allows direct interface to all packages. And it also connects to Octave: [reference/sage/interfaces/octave](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/interfaces/octave.html)

Comment: That's the answer to the question then J.D.  Do it.

Comment: I did but OP should wait for more definitive answer from someone who has a first hand experience with `octave-symbolic` or Sage's `octave.eval`.

Answer (score 7):

Sage uses *many* symbolic computation packages: Maxima, Singular, etc. For each functionality, it picks the most suitable algorithm from all the packages. It also allows direct interface to all packages.

FWIW, Sage also connects to Octave. Consult: [reference/sage/interfaces/octave](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/interfaces/octave.html).

MATLAB has a symbolic toolbox where it allows defining symbolic variables via `syms` and manipulate them etc. It seems that `Octave-symbolic` is a package that allows Octave to do symbolic computations similar to MATLAB's. Link: http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/

Comment: for octave-symbolic installation: `sudo apt-get install octave-symbolic`

Comment: @seyed Or within octave: `pkg install -forge symbolic`