# How to get PI based results in Octave?

Tags: matlab, pi, octave

In Octave

```
octave.exe:4> asin(1/2)
ans =  0.52360
```

is it possible to get the result in form of:

```
ans = pi/6
```

It seems not possible with [format function](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/format.html), but may be there are any tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's the same as with Matlab, where you would do sym(asin(1/2)).

Comment: This relies on the symbolic toolbox in matlab, so probably you will need a package like described here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128812/is-there-a-symbolic-math-package-for-octave

Answer (score 2):

An alternative might be to convert into units of $\pi$ explicitly, and then seek a rational approximation:

```
> rats(asin(1/2) / pi)                                                                                                                                    
ans =       1/6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "format rat".  "rat" stands for rational, which puts answers in fractional terms.  Using "format rat" puts ALL terms in fractional terms (unless you switch back to a different format such as "format g"), as opposed to rats([expression]), which (I assume - I've never used that) only puts [expression] in rational terms.